# Html,css: Change a row's border colow on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using DataTables and i am trying to change the row's top and bottom border to red on row hover.
Following didn't change the color.

```
table.dataTable.hover tbody tr:hover,
table.dataTable.hover tbody tr.odd:hover,
table.dataTable.hover tbody tr.even:hover,
table.dataTable.display tbody tr:hover,
table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd:hover,
table.dataTable.display tbody tr.even:hover {
    background-color: rgba(209, 231, 255, 0.5); 
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    border-top: 1px solid red;
}
```

Anyone knows how to properly do this ? 
jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d1zqsayh/

Comment: We need to see the HTML as well.

Comment: What does your html code look like? Please post it and make a jsfiddle.

Comment: @Shomz @i alarmed alien http://jsfiddle.net/d1zqsayh/

Comment: Please don't use jsfiddle in your work, a new feature called "Stack Overflow Snippets" has been released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
table.dataTable tbody tr td{
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}

table.dataTable tbody tr:hover td {
    border-top: red 1px solid;
    border-bottom: red 1px solid;
}
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/d1zqsayh/21/

Comment: if i use `table.dataTable tbody tr td{
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}` my old borders are gone , and if i don't, my rows move strangely

Comment: Ah, sorry, use just the border-bottom there and both top and bottom for the hover. http://jsfiddle.net/d1zqsayh/21/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/d1zqsayh/22/  check this out. i only changed  the color `1px solid rgb(192, 220, 255);`

Comment: do you see what i mean with double border? it appears on the bottom border only

Comment: if you find something let me know... cause i literally tried everything i could think of...

Comment: Sorry, I was out. Anyway, this is a standard thing - the doubling comes from the bottom border of the top element touching the top border of the bottom element, so instead of a 1px border, you have two 1px lines touching, creating a 2px border.

Comment: http://grooveshark.com/#!/album/Halo+LP/5904939  how does this website has the border normal ?

Comment: They are using the top margin -1px, so the two borders from my previous comment overlap.

Comment: where should i add `top margin -1px` ?

Comment: I don't think it's going to be that easy because you're using tables (which should be used just for the tabular data), the site you shown me uses regular divs to build the layout so all they need to do is to set that margin rule on their row divs, but I doubt it can work just as easy on the `tr` elements without breaking the table.

Comment: why would it be hard when there is a fully editable .css file ? i dont get it.. :S this is DataTables too, very famous plugin

Comment: Try to do it then. **Tables are not for building layout**, there are tons of topics about that. Table elements don't respond to margins, and if you set them to be inline-blocks or something, they might break in certain browser (maybe all). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html

Comment: there has to be some way of removing the double border , i dont understand what building layout means

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/d1zqsayh/28/ , i am so close to doing it with divs , check the first 17 rows . am i close ? do you see what i am missing ?

Comment: I think you're now farther than where you were - now each cell gets the bottom margin on hover, and see what happens when you hover the cells in the first column. Like I said, the table elements don't play well with margins. If you wish to stick with tables, perhaps the easist would be to change only the top border (which you already have in a non-hover states) and the row background. Otherwise, you'll just going to torture yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set a border on a `tr`, so you need to set it on the `td` elements.

First, set a default state with "invisible" borders -- this rule will apply to tables with the classes `dataTable` and `hover`:

```
.dataTable.hover td {
    border: 1px solid inherit;
}
```

Now specify red top and bottom borders when the row is hovered:

```
.dataTable.hover tr:hover td {
    border-top: 1px solid red;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d1zqsayh/12/)

In general, it is best not to specify too many selectors when setting css rules. Your selectors are very specific, and could be replaced by shorter statements, e.g.

```
.dataTable tr:hover td {
    background-color: rgba(209, 231, 255, 0.5); 
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    border-top: 1px solid red;
}
```

instead of `table.dataTable tbody tr.even:hover td`, etc.

Comment: why does this make the table's rows move awkwardly ?

Comment: Because the border is being added to the elements. One of the earlier style declarations is overriding the border declaration `.dataTable.hover td` and making only the top border appear. As I said, it is best not to specify too many selectors when setting rules, because you can accidentally make a declaration very specific, which then makes it very difficult to override without using something like `! important`.

Answer (score 0):

You cant set a border to a TR  try this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
 <HEAD>
 <style>


    .redrow td:hover{
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    border-top: 1px solid red;
    }
 </style>

 </HEAD>

 <BODY>
  <TABLE>
  <TR class="redrow">
    <TD>dsfsdfs</TD>
  </TR>
  </TABLE>
 </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: That would change only one cell's border.

Comment: i forgot to add the td try again now :)

Comment: It would still change only one cell's border.

Comment: Sorry you didnt post any html so i didnt knew you where using multiple cells. Post your html please.

Comment: The OP said "row". Also your HTML isn't valid: `</HTML`.

Comment: There is no border on a row in html and are you seriously whining about a missing > a the the end of the sample, how are you helping out here ?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with the border-collapse attribute:

```
table, th, td {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Full code: http://jsfiddle.net/hkmgk3uf/